# Position element relative to its center

Tags: html, css

I assume it should be possible to easily position an element with anchor point in its center so that when I move it, position it, scale it - it remains centered for the coordinates provided.

I create circles with different sizes and coordinates so I experience issues centering them without preemptively knowing their exact position preemptively.

See the following code:

```js
function start() {
  anime({
    targets: document.querySelector('.g-circle'),
    opacity: [0.3, 1],
    scale: [0.3, 1],
    translateX: '-50%',
    translateY: '-50%',
    easing: 'linear',
    duration: 1000
  });
}

document.querySelector('.start').addEventListener('click', start);
```

```css
#action-area {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left: 10%;
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
  background: #000;
}

.g-circle {
  position: absolute;
  width: 10vh;
  height: 10vh;
  background-color: aqua;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 0.5vh solid #000;
  
  opacity: 0.3;
  transform-origin: center;
  user-select: none;
  transform: scale(0.3) translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}

.g-circle > div {
  font-size: 104px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  line-height: 100%;
  margin-top: calc(50% - 52px);
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="action-area">
  <div class="g-circle" style="left: 50%; top: 50%;">
    <div>1</div>
  </div>
</div>
<button class="start">Start</button>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/3.2.1/anime.min.js"></script>
```

I want the element to stay in 1 place and scale smoothly in all directions. I don't understand why it recenters as I click on the start button, it was already centered using `translateX` and `translateY` and when I applied it again it, for some reason, moves even further.

Any way I can achieve the desired result without restructuring the HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Translate then scale and don't animate translation (keep both start and end value the same inside `animate`)

```js
function start() {
  anime({
    targets: document.querySelector('.g-circle'),
    opacity: [0.3, 1],
    translateX: ['-50%', '-50%'],
    translateY: ['-50%', '-50%'],
    scale: [0.3, 1],
    easing: 'linear',
    duration: 1000
  });
}

document.querySelector('.start').addEventListener('click', start);
```

```css
#action-area {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left: 10%;
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
  background: #000;
}

.g-circle {
  position: absolute;
  width: 10vh;
  height: 10vh;
  background-color: aqua;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 0.5vh solid #000;
  
  opacity: 0.3;
  transform-origin: center;
  user-select: none;
  transform:  translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%) scale(0.3);
}

.g-circle > div {
  font-size: 104px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  line-height: 100%;
  margin-top: calc(50% - 52px);
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="action-area">
  <div class="g-circle">
    <div>1</div>
  </div>
</div>
<button class="start">Start</button>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/3.2.1/anime.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I updated the question with the coordinates. Could you see this: https://codepen.io/Telion/pen/RwoGWvq ? It's still moving a bit to the left.

Comment: @Telion translate then scale (you need to edit the CSS too)

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry. Just tested and it works as expected. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

I believe you want something like this

```js
start = () => anime({
  targets: document.querySelector('.g-circle'),
  opacity: [0.3, 1],
  scale: [0.3, 1],
  top: '50%',
  left: '50%',
  translateX: '-50%',
  translateY: '-50%',
  easing: 'linear',
  duration: 1000
});

document.querySelector('.start').addEventListener('click', start);
```

```css
#action-area {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left: 10%;
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
  background: #000;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.g-circle {
  position: absolute;
  width: 10vh;
  height: 10vh;
  background-color: aqua;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 0.5vh solid #000;
  opacity: 0.3;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  user-select: none;
}

.g-circle > div {
  font-size: 104px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  line-height: 100%;
  margin-top: calc(50% - 52px);
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="action-area">
  <div class="g-circle">
    <div>1</div>
  </div>
</div>
<button class="start">Start</button>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/3.2.1/anime.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I don't want element to move to the center. I want it to scale from the position where it's located and have absolutely no movement anywhere. That's the issue here, because at the moment when I try to scale it, `translate` gets overwritten and element moves to the side.